# How to use PnP Powershell to find subsites of subsites?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, pnp-powershell

I'm trying to create an array of all subsites in our tenant.
I'm able to get the first level of subsites but not the next level in a recursive manner.

Here's my code so far:

```
Connect-PnpOnline -Url XXX -Credentials XXX

$allSubwebs = @()

$currentSubwebs = Get-PnPSubwebs

foreach ($currentSubweb in $currentSubWebs) {
    $allSubwebs += $currentSubWeb.ServerRelativeUrl 
}
```

So this gives me the first layer of sub sites. But I know that some sub sites contain sub sites themselves. Of course I could nest foreach() loops but for this I would have to know in advance how many layers of subsites there are.

So my question is how I can do this recursively, i.e. drill down and populate the array.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `Recurse` parameter.

Modify your code as below:

```
$currentSubwebs = Get-PnPSubWebs -Recurse
```

Reference - [Get-PnPSubwebs](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-Guidance/blob/master/powershell/GetPnPSubWebs.md)